# How can we use Sikuli with Selenium in Python?

Tags: selenium, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I know that how we can use Sikuli in Java. But I have some code in Python which is automating a web application, and I want to use Sikuli in it. I searched a lot on the Internet about how we can use Sikuli in Python. But I did not find any good resource related to it.

How can I import Sikuli script in a Python project in Eclipse? When I added the sikuli-script.jar file in the Python path in Eclipse and when I am trying to use

```
import * from sikuli
```

Then I am getting "there is no such type of module named sikuli".

Comment: This error usually pops out when a module (namely, `sikuli`) is not installed. You need to install `sikuli` using `pip`, the Python package manager thanks to `pip install sikuli` and so then you can import it in your code

Answer (score 1):

Sikuli is a tool written in Java and hence you can't use it in your Python code as is. Instead you have the option to use it within a Jython environment, that provides you the Python syntax and enables running jar packages. If you are not using many third party Python libraries and mainly stick to the generic functionality, you shouldn't get into too much trouble transferring from pure Python to Jython.

There are clear instructions of how to use Sikuli with Jython on SikuliX official website. If you have any related questions, you can post the [here](https://launchpad.net/sikuli).