# How do I upload multiple images to Instagram using python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I'm currently working on an Instagram bot and want to upload pictures using selenium. I'm emulating a phone in my selenium, but everytime I click on the upload button, Explorer opens and wants me to select the pictures manually.
Is there a way to bypass that to have picture uploads automated?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is simply a web Automator and is of no use for handling file selectors, or any of that kind that is distinct from web functionalities.

That being said, I do believe this can be solved by using a library called `Sikuli`. See [this article](https://www.guru99.com/sikuli-tutorial.html) on the use of this and how you can incorporate this into your script. Also see this answers for [How to use Sikuli with Selenium in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302624/how-can-we-use-sikuli-with-selenium-in-python)

The other way is to of-course use the `API`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload pictures on instagram from python using a library called [instabot](https://pypi.org/project/instabot/)

Then did the following:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
bot.upload_photo(IMAGE_PATH, caption="Follow me on instagram! :D")
```

Note: you might get an error when running the script more than once. To overcome this, you might want to delete your `config` folder. Or make a script that automates such task.